# Split rows into multiple rows based on string length of column Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
+---------------+---------------+-------------+
| employee_name |     role      | date_joined |
+---------------+---------------+-------------+
| John          |      10013004 | 2018-01-09  |
| Jane          |          1004 | 2020-08-09  |
| Sam           |  100380003000 | 2022-03-31  |
+---------------+---------------+-------------+
```

I want to convert the above table in the format below, where the role column string should be split into groups of 4 and should be added as new entry.

```
+---------------+-------+-------------+
| employee_name | role  | date_joined |
+---------------+-------+-------------+
| John          |  1001 | 2018-01-09  |
| John          |  3004 | 2018-01-09  |
| Jane          |  1004 | 2020-08-09  |
| Sam           |  1003 | 2022-03-31  |
| Sam           |  8000 | 2022-03-31  |
| Sam           |  3000 | 2022-03-31  |
+---------------+-------+-------------+
```

Any idea how can I achieve the following?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp_matches()` to generate rows with those 4 character substrings:

```
select t.employee_name,
       x.role[1] as role,
       x.pos,
       t.date_joined
from the_table t
  cross join regexp_matches(t.role, '[0-9]{4}', 'g') with ordinality as x(role, pos)       
order by t.employee_name, t.date_joined
```

`regexp_matches()` returns an array of matches, that's why the `x.role[1]` is required.

If the column can contain other characters, not just numbers, use `'.{4}'` instead of `'[0-9]{4}'`

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/aaTd1kb1)

Comment: you could also directly `SELECT t.employee_name, regexp_matches(t.role, '[0-9]{4}', 'g')[1], t.date_joined FROM the_table t`

Comment: @Edouard: it is recommended to use set returning functions in the FROM clause, rather than the SELECT list.

Comment: _no_name : is this recommendation in the postgres manual ? It don't see here the advantage of putting the function in the `FROM`clause.

Comment: @Edouard: would you put a `select * from some_table` into the SELECT list? That's no different than putting a set-returning function into the SELECT list

Comment: @Edouard: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) "*They are used like a table, view, or subquery in the FROM clause of a query*"

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this works great for me, I will mark this as correct.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Just one quick question, is there any way I can add a position column where I can show the position of the role For eg: for first four characters the position should be 1 and and next four position is 2 and so on.